# CsvItemExporter for multiple files in custom item pipeline not exporting all items

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I have created an item pipeline as an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63749285/python-scrapy-how-to-save-data-in-different-files/65002980#65002980) question.
It is supposed to create a new file for every page according to the `page_no` value set in the item. This works mostly fine.
The problem is with the last csv file generated by the pipeline/item exporter, `page-10.csv`.
The last 10 values are not exported, so the file stays empty.
What could be the reason for this behaviour?

**pipelines.py**

```py
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter

class PerFilenameExportPipeline:
    """Distribute items across multiple CSV files according to their 'page_no' field"""

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.filename_to_exporter = {}

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        for exporter in self.filename_to_exporter.values():
            exporter.finish_exporting()

    def _exporter_for_item(self, item):
        filename = 'page-' + str(item['page_no'])
        del item['page_no']
        if filename not in self.filename_to_exporter:
            f = open(f'{filename}.csv', 'wb')
            exporter = CsvItemExporter(f, export_empty_fields=True)
            exporter.start_exporting()
            self.filename_to_exporter[filename] = exporter
        return self.filename_to_exporter[filename]

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        exporter = self._exporter_for_item(item)
        exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```

**spider**

```py
import scrapy
from ..pipelines import PerFilenameExportPipeline


class spidey(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "idk"
    custom_settings = {
        'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
            PerFilenameExportPipeline: 100
        }
    }
    
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request("http://quotes.toscrape.com/", cb_kwargs={'page_no': 1})

    def parse(self, response, page_no):
        for qts in response.xpath("//*[@class=\"quote\"]"):
            yield {
                'page_no': page_no,
                'author' : qts.xpath("./span[2]/small/text()").get(),
                'quote' : qts.xpath("./*[@class=\"text\"]/text()").get()
            }

        next_pg = response.xpath('//li[@class="next"]/a/@href').get()      
        if next_pg is not None:
            yield response.follow(next_pg, cb_kwargs={'page_no': page_no + 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, 2 years later, but still - it might turn out helpful for someone.

It looks like you're never closing the file you're writing to (as you're using inline *open*). Please compare your code to the one in Scrapy's docs (the "Using Item Exporters" section): https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html

Besides, the method should now be called "close_spider", not "spider_closed"

Changing your code to the following should help:

```py
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter

class PerFilenameExportPipeline:

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.filename_to_exporter = {}

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        #iterating over exporter-file tuples instead of only exporters
        for exporter, csv_file in self.filename_to_exporter.values():
            exporter.finish_exporting()
            #closing the file
            csv_file.close()

    def _exporter_for_item(self, item):
        filename = 'page-' + str(item['page_no'])
        del item['page_no']
        if filename not in self.filename_to_exporter:
            csv_file = open(f'{filename}.csv', 'wb')
            exporter = CsvItemExporter(f, export_empty_fields=True)
            exporter.start_exporting()
            #adding both exporter & file to later be closed as the dict's value
            self.filename_to_exporter[filename] = (exporter, csv_file)

        #picking only the exporter via [0]
        return self.filename_to_exporter[filename][0]

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        exporter = self._exporter_for_item(item)
        exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```